# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown and halts the selenium test run

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using firefox webdriver running firefox 41.0.2
Nunit 3.4.1
selenium 2.47.0
specflow 2.1.0
My tests run in parallel.

Passed couple days my tests have been failing to complete while running through jenkins, the run gets stuck on a process and cannot continue with the rest of the run. I have intermittently been able to reproduce the error locally when running 20+ scenarios. I am getting the below exception, has anyone seen this issue before?

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7056/hub/session/d0a83b9c-bd79-4218-8eac-dc8b273f8f40/element/%7B84966a91-06c4-42dd-98c0-278ed35e3667%7D/attribute/value.
>
> The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: Unable to connect to the remote server
>     ----> System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
>     ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:7056
>
> +++++++++++++++++++
>   STACK TRACE:
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAttribute(String attributeName)
>      at TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.WebComponents.Pages.WeeklySalesForecastPage.<Save>b__0(IWebElement s) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Automation Build Develop\workspace\TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.WebComponents\Pages\WeeklySalesForecastPage.cs:line 38
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.WebComponents.Pages.WeeklySalesForecastPage.Save() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Automation Build Develop\workspace\TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.WebComponents\Pages\WeeklySalesForecastPage.cs:line 39
>      at TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.CommonSteps.Steps.SalesForecast.WeeklySalesForecastGraphsSteps.WhenISaveTheForecast() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Automation Build Develop\workspace\TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.CommonSteps\Steps\SalesForecast\WeeklySalesForecastGraphsSteps.cs:line 73
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>      at TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.RegresionTests.Features.Schedule.ScheduleGraphFeature.ScenarioCleanup() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Automation Build Develop\workspace\TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.RegresionTests\Features\Schedule\ScheduleGraph.feature.cs:line 0
>      at TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.RegresionTests.Features.Schedule.ScheduleGraphFeature.VerifyScheduleGraphShowsCorrectPeopleAndOverstaffedWhenDemandIsExceeded(String role, String tab, String link, String noOfItems, String peopleRequired, String itemsOrSales, String tab2, String view, String total, String tab3, String type1, String type2, String type3, String[] exampleTags) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Automation Build Develop\workspace\TeamHours.Automation.StandAlone.RegresionTests\Features\Schedule\ScheduleGraph.feature:line 133
>   --WebException
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>   --SocketException
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Answer (score 5):

We found this issue could be related to TCP ports being exhausted on the host machine. There is other material out there about this but basically the web driver exhausts all the ports where they get stuck in a waiting state due to the driver polling the OS for an available port. The fix involved modifying the registry to either increase the number of available ports or decrease the amount of time they are in the waiting state.

Comment: I've already set my MaxUserPort to '65534' and TcpTimedWaitDelay to '30' (lowest it can go). Do you remember your settings? I'm suffering from the same port exhaustion problem.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a hour of time I was able to find the exact issue. In my case, I was using the versions as below from Nuget Package Manager.

1. Selenium.Support - v3.13.1
2. Selenium.WebDriver - v3.13.1
3. Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver - v3.13.0

After downgrading those to lower version as below, evrything was working as expected.

1. Selenium.Support - v3.12.1
2. Selenium.WebDriver - v3.12.1
3. Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver - v3.12.0

Answer (score 2):

This Issue may Occurs unreachable of your launched port. So that your Browser Window got Closed, In this case Each Testcase refer the QuitDriver instead of Next Test Case, the quit driver must triggered after completing the testsuite. In Selenium we need to use [OneTimeTearDown] instead of [TearDown]..

Answer (score 1):

When I've had this error, and the answer has always been "update the ****driver.exe". In my case ChromeDriver.exe, in your case it's probably the FireFoxDriver.exe

Answer (score 1):

For my case I was early disposing the driver with `using` statement.

```
 using   IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Programs2\\chromedriver", options);
```

I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the incompatibility of ***GeckoDriver.exe/ ChromeDriver.exe/ IEDriverServer.exe*** with their respective browser is causing this issue.

I was facing the same issue and updating my chrome browser to latest worked out for me. So upgrading/degrading your browser (or) the respective driver could help resolving this issue.

In a nutshell, you have to keep you browser in sync with the compatible version of respective driver.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because you (**for some reason**) have two version of browser-driver folder exist in my project **FOLDER** intentionally.

**Background:**
Assume you use Nuget-Package-Manager to install selenium web driver, then you will have a folder called 'packages' under your project.

Inside the 'packages' folder, you will see all NuGet-packages you installed for your solution.

**Where problem possible lies:** 
There are 2 different version of Firefox driver in the 'packages' folder: 0.20 and 0.21.

Once I removed the 0.20 folder and just keep the 0.21, the problem is gone.

**Possible reason:**
You've been working on this project for a while and got several branches, you have different web driver NuGet versions in different branches.

When you merge from one to another, somehow the low version is not deleted automatically but the new version got installed as well and both versions all exist.

[2 different versions of the same web driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coeiq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used `[OneTimeTearDown]` instead of `[TearDown]` and it worked.

Comment: This has already been suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473241/1839439

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.